# Sorting a custom class

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to sort a custom class, the code has no errors but does not sort the list by Coulmn1 as required?

```
Class MainWindow

    Private Rows As New List(Of Row)
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "Z", .Column2 = 2})
        Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "D", .Column2 = 1})
        Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "S", .Column2 = 2})
        Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "A", .Column2 = 1})

        Rows.Sort(Function(x As Row, y As Row) x.Column1.CompareTo(y.Column1))
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Row
    Public Property Column1 As String
    Public Property Column2 As Int32
End Class
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you are testing your sorted list? It looks like your sort should work and its not clear how you have determined it isn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this helps..

This one using **OrderBy**.

```
Class MainWindow

Private Rows As New List(Of Row)
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "Z", .Column2 = 2})
    Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "D", .Column2 = 1})
    Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "S", .Column2 = 2})
    Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "A", .Column2 = 1})

    Rows = Rows.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Column1).ToList()
    Rows = Rows.OrderBy(Function(y) y.Column1).ToList()

End Sub
End Class
Public Class Row
    Public Property Column1 As String
    Public Property Column2 As Int32
End Class
```

And this one using **Sort**.

```
Class MainWindow

Private Rows As New List(Of Row)
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "Z", .Column2 = 2})
    Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "D", .Column2 = 1})
    Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "S", .Column2 = 2})
    Rows.Add(New Row With {.Column1 = "A", .Column2 = 1})

    Rows.Sort(Function(x As Row, y As Row) x.Column1.CompareTo(y.Column1))
    Rows.Sort(Function(x As Row, y As Row) x.Column2.CompareTo(y.Column2))

End Sub
End Class
Public Class Row
    Public Property Column1 As String
    Public Property Column2 As Int32
End Class
```

Comment: In both cases your first sort is being discarded when you do the second.

Comment: Yes i know that, but i don't really understand his problem exactly, if he wants to sort both or not. Thanks..

Comment: But you are not sorting with both. You are sorting once, throwing away that sorted result and then sorting again (in the first case the same sort, in the second case you are sorting by column 2 and not column 1 at all). Did you mean to sort by both (eg by using `ThenBy` in the first case)?

Comment: I already used `ThenBy` but my codes seems wrong.. This one `Rows = Rows.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Column1).ToList() _ 
                        .ThenBy(Function(y) y.Column2).ToList()` .. Is that right???

Comment: `ThenBy` needs to be used directly after an `OrderBy`. You mustn't have the ToList in between. eg `Rows.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...).ToList()`

Comment: to make the second one work then you need a single function that will compare both columns. So if column compare is non zero then you return that and if it is zero then you return the column compare for column 2. Its a trickier function to write well though.

Comment: `Rows.OrderBy(Function(c As Row) c.Column1). _
                      ThenBy(Function(x As Row) x.Column2).ToList` .. This one work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help